# $ \mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(\{0\},\{1\},\{2\}, \dots , \{n\})$ showing $\cup_{n\geq0} \mathcal{F}_n $ is not a sigma algebra, do not understand.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Isn't this countable union equal to the sigma algebra generated by the singletons of the natural numbers, which is the class of subsets of the natural numbers where the set is either or countable or its complement is countable. And we know that this class IS a sigma algebra.

So isn't saying this isn't a sigma algebra a contradiction.

Comment: The first statement you make is false : just taking the union of various sigma-algebras could not give you the sigma-algebra generated by putting all those sigma-algebras together.

Comment: Concerning your tags, this has nothing to do with abstract algebra and algebraic topology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\mathcal F =\bigcup_{n\ge 0} \mathcal F_n$$ isn’t closed under countable union.

For example, all the singletons $A_n = \{n^2\}$ belong to $\mathcal F$. However, the countable union $\cup_n A_n = \{n^2: n \in \mathbb N\}$ does not belong to $\mathcal F$ as it belongs to none of the $\mathcal F_n$.

$$\mathcal F \neq \sigma(\{0\}, \{1\}, \dots )$$

**Note:** you don't want to use the singletons $A_n = \{n\}$ to create your counterexample because $\cup_n A_n = \mathbb N$ belongs to all of the $\mathcal F_n$ (a sigma algebra over a set $X$ always contains the empty set and $X$)

Comment: Ok so the countable union does not contain the set of natural numbers and therefore can  not be the sigma algebra generated by its singletons.

Comment: This is exact !